# What does "ld: mach-o string pool extends beyond end of file" mean?

Tags: xcode, clang, gfortran

I am currently trying to make and install a specialist suite of software (https://github.com/scottransom/presto), and am encountering this error:

```
gfortran -g -fPIC -o /path-to/presto/bin/psrorbit powerplot.o xyline.o psrorbit.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/cfitsio/3.450/lib -lcfitsio -lcurl -L/path-to/presto/lib -lpresto -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3f -L/usr/local/lib/pgplot -lcpgplot -lpgplot -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11 -L/opt/X11/lib -lpng16 -lm
ld: mach-o string pool extends beyond end of file in /usr/local/lib/libcpgplot.dylib file '/usr/local/lib/libcpgplot.dylib' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [psrorbit] Error 1
```

I don't think it's a problem related to PRESTO per se, as several searches (see [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/18), [this](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/issues/795), and [this](https://twitter.com/drance/status/225478871628267520?lang=en)) point to something fundamental, perhaps with Xcode. I currently have version 11.3, and I also installed the command line tools. So again, what does the error itself mean? Any help would be useful!

Comment: I'm facing this error message with a different project. Maybe something to do with incremental compilation/linking ([source](https://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Mar/msg00849.html))? Or maybe a bug with the `strip` program ([source](https://twitter.com/zadr/status/231189953500041216?lang=en))?

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of the source code for [Apple's version of `ld`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-274.2/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp.auto.html), this error means that the symbol table in an object prematurely ends when the file does.

There appear to be quite a few sanity checks performed on object files when linking. Likely, your copy of `/usr/local/lib/libcpgplot.dylib` is corrupt.

Comment: In my case, the object file I was linking against was corrupt. I was able to resolve this error by re-downloading a copy of the affected dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I stashed my latest changes to where I remember it was building successfully and the issue persisted.

So what worked for me:
**Run CMD + Shift + K in Xcode;
Close Xcode;
Run in Terminal**

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

After that, I have launched Xcode and the issue was resolved. Not sure why it appeared and not sure why it went away. Just Xcode making my work time more diverse, I suppose